# Forcing all PC internet traffic to pass through Tor on kali-Linux

Tags: help, linux

It is known that VPN connection forces all internet traffic to pass through it, but in case of Tor, user must configure internet apps to pass through the proxy built by Tor. Some internet apps can not be set to use proxies.
So, the question:

Is there a way to force all internet traffic to pass through TOR proxy in kali-Linux operating system.Note that I am a newbie to Tor and Kali.